# Rudin: set of $n$ tuples are countable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to work through Theorem 2.13 in Rudin, which states;

> Let $A$ be a countable set, and let $B_n$ be the set of all $n$-tuples $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ where $a_k \in A$) ($k = 1, \ldots, n$), and the elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ need not be distinct. Then $B_n$ is countable.

Rudin proves it by induction on $n$. The base case is rather obvious since $B_1 = A$ and $A$ is countable by assumption. Supposing $B_{n-1}$ is countable, where
$$B_{n-1} := \{(a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1} \mid a_i \in A\},$$
we consider $B_n$, where 
$$B_n := \{(a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}, a_n) \mid a_i \in A\}.$$
This is where my confusion comes in, and it is mostly a notational issue. Rudin instead writes $B_n$ as the set of order pairs $(b,a)$ where $b \in B_{n-1}$ and $a \in A$. This is, in effect, an $(n-1)$-tuple within an $n$-tuple,i.e., 
$$((a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}), a)$$
if in fact we were considering an element of $B_{n-1}$.

My question is: why can he call it $(b,a)$? Is this just an abuse of notation? The argument for why this establishes that $B_n$ is countable makes sense to me, and even if the solution is just that this is a reasonable way to list it, I would be fine with that. But the notion of calling this an ordered pair with element $b \in B_{n-1}$ is what is tripping me up.

Comment: It seems to me you quoted the wrong part of the book. The quote that we need is where you claim he's "calling this an ordered pair". I doubt that this can be cleared up without the exact wording that he uses for this.

Comment: He doesn't directly call this an ordered pair, but an $n$-tuple is an ordered list, is it not?

Comment: I've looked it up in the meantime. I think you're right, he pretty much equates it with an ordered pair. It's just that for such a high proportion of questions it turns out that the problem was due to incorrect paraphrasing of the original, and this wastes so much time, that I no longer respond to questions about errors in texts unless the text is quoted verbatim.

Comment: I completely understand your point. In the future, I will be sure to more precisely quote the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is an abuse of notation. But this can be justified since there exists a bijection $((a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1}),a)\mapsto (a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1},a)$. This step is just omitted since it is too trivial.

Comment: There are different ways to define $B_n$ for $n\ge 3.$ One way is recursively : $B_n=B_{n-1}\times A,$ which conforms with Rudin's proof.  What is Rudin's def'n?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Your point is true, but John.P’s question was ‘Is notation $(b,a)$ correct?’, not much related with the definition of $B_n$’s.

Comment: If Rudin's def'n is the one I mentioned then his notation is correct and is not an abuse.

Comment: $B_n$ is the set of $n$-tuples. He doesn't define it as $B_{n-1} \times A$, but this is a very good point. (Then again, wouldn't the same issue be at play in the sense that an element of $B_{n-1}$ is itself an ordered tuple?)

Comment: Actually, I see your point. If $B_n = B_{n-1} \times A$, then $(b,a) = ((a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}), a_n)$ already, so it's an ordered tuple within an ordered tuple. With that said, the bijection in Jingeon's post makes the most sense to me.